# What gives THREE.js canvas double size pixles?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, pixel, resolution

I am trying to use **THREE.js** for the first time and it seems easy enough. However there is one thing that I just can't get right;

for some strange reason, the canvas pixels are "double" size. Please see the following screenshot:
[image: double pixels in THREE.js canvas]

Please note the following:

1. The canvas is the orange part
2. The page background is the white part
3. The black border of the div that contains the canvas is exactly 1 pixel wide

You can see the rendered lines (GridHelper) are not one pixel wide as expected, but seems to be double size, or at least larger than one.

I set up the render like this:

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias:false
    , alpha: true 
});
console.log("canvas", this.renderer.domElement);
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 1000);
```

I call the following function at every render:

```
update_canvas_size() {
        const canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
        const parent = canvas.parentElement;
        // look up the size the canvas is being displayed
        const w = parent.clientWidth;
        const h = parent.clientHeight;
        console.log("update_canvas_size <",canvas.width,canvas.height,"> --> <", w,h,">");
        
        // adjust displayBuffer size to match
        if (canvas.width !== w || canvas.height !== h) {
            console.log("SIZE DESCREPENCY DETECTED, RESIZING <",canvas.width,canvas.height,"> --> <", w,h,">");
            this.renderer.setSize(w, h, false);
            this.camera.aspect = w / h;
            this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            

        }
    }
```

And in case you wonder what my GridHelper looks like:

```
    this.grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 10, 10, 0x666666, 0x777777);
```

What can cause this?

Comment: It’s not just aliasing?

Comment: No, the black 1-pixel border is sharp while the grid lines are blurry and double-sized. I realize imgurl did a job ion the image. (I can try to scale it up to make it clearer.

Comment: [dpr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) may be causing the problem.

Comment: The border is vertical; no antialiasing is needed.